# Mute audio coming from another webpage in <embed>

Tags: html

I'm using "embed" to pull elements from another webpage, and those elements make noise. How can I mute this audio?

For some more context, this isn't going on a website or anything, this is simply an html file I'm using to compact some things I use for work to try and save desktop space.

Edit: Here is the code

```
<div>
   <embed src="http://website.com/webpage" style="width:100%;height:10%;background-color:#191919;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is clear but better to add your code to question.

Comment: Show us a dummy link for the embed.

Comment: I din't find any solution for `embed` but there is some solution for `iframe` if you whould to use.

Comment: Yeah, iframe works fine. Won't cause any issues.

Comment: I have found a work around by enabling tab specific muting in Google Chrome. This solves my problem, however I'm sure if someone else has this same issue, this work around will not suffice.